# How can I split a list of divs into two columns if there's enough space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have 8 divs. I want them to be split into two columns like this if there's enough space (via `min-width`):

```
 1  5
 2  6
 3  7
 4  8
```

However, if I simply set `display: inline-block`, they instead get split like this, which is not what I want:

```
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
```

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that allows for unequal sizes, so if there's only 6, but #1 and #2 are of double height, the result will look like this:

```
1  3
1  4
2  5
2  6
```

Is this possible in pure CSS? Or, if not, how can this be done in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Columns to achieve this behavior:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.columnWrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 10rem;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.columnWrapper {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  -moz-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .columnWrapper {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columnWrapper">
  <div>1</div
  ><div>2</div
  ><div>3</div
  ><div>4</div
  ><div>5</div
  ><div>6</div
  ><div>7</div
  ><div>8</div>
</div>
```

Or see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3z5eq4h3/) fiddle.

For the case that there are only six elements, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p6cpzjj9/) fiddle (same code).